# Where to find Percona Configuration file?

Tags: mysql, percona

Recently I have installed Percona 5.7.12 in my linux box but I have not found any configuration file(like my.cnf for mysql) where i can set/modify global variables.
I want to change the values of default system variables like 'sql_mode', password_policy etc.I tried setting values like `*SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';*` but after restart of mysqld instance, it seems old default values are retained.How can I set those values permanently so that modified values are retained??? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Percona's install guide](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html), the config file should be located under `/etc/my.cnf`:

> Percona Server stores the data files in /var/lib/mysql/ by default. You can find the configuration file that is used to manage Percona Server in /etc/my.cnf.

If there is no such file in the `/etc` directory, then you can create it yourself and set any config parameters there. Parameters in the config file are preserved across MySQL system restarts.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow for your reply..by default my.cnf not created during installation but i had to create it manually and then it worked.

Comment: Check /etc/mysql/ too. For some reason, this is where Ubuntu/Debian store their my.cnf while RHEL flavors just use /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

It's this file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` in my Percona 5.7 installation.

I can find it by following these steps:

```
mysqladmin --help
```

The output contains these lines:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

The first file (/etc/my.cnf) doesn't exist on my machine.

The second one (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) contains these lines:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/percona-server.conf.d/
```

This file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` in the first directory contains the settings I would expect in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue. Found that the xtrabackup versions at both the servers were way different (8.0.23 at the source where the backup was taken and 2.4.9 at the destination where I was trying to restore the backup).

As soon as I upgraded the xtrabackup version to 8.0.23 on the destination server, the "prepare" went smoothly without any issues.